# Django on model save add warning to JSON (DRF)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Sometimes, when I save a model, it does not Validate well. So it returns a ValidationError (400 BAD REQUEST).

Sometimes, when I save a model, it saves very well. So it returns a HTTP 200 (OK).

Sometimes, I know what my user means, but it is not so nice. I can save it, but I have to change something else as well. And I know what to change. So I want to be nice to my user, since he is my best friend. I would like to give a warning when my model does a save(). This warning should be returned as an extra field. the WarningField. Which is normally empty (of course). But when it is not, my Django Rest Framework should unpack it and add it to the json response. So I can get it on the client side in the done method with my Javascript.

Is there any already existent support for the WarningField or shall I write it myself? Any suggestions?

Comment: What database are you using. Generally serializer returns error in the json response itself. `DocumentSerializer` in `rest framework mongoengine` does not return the validation done by the save method of the document. So it ends up having a 500 internal server error response. You can catch the exception and use let the serializer return a 400 status code. You can then use this 400 bad request response to show the user your problems and kind of give warning.

Comment: Did you even read what I asked? The errors are going all fine. It's just that I though that there should be something in between of an error and succes, namely succes with warning. How to do this on the model level and implement this into DRF, that is my question.

Comment: @gabn88 - Did you find a way to add warning to response?